Property 'list' does not exist on type 'DatabaseReference'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {

 
  config = {
    apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
  };

  app = initializeApp(this.config);
  database = getDatabase(this.app);
  messagesRef = ref(this.database, "messages");

  constructor() {}

  
  sendMessage(newMessage: string) {
    if (newMessage.trim()) {
      push(this.messagesRef, {
        text: newMessage,
        createdAt: new Date().toString()
      });
    }
  }

  
  getMessages(): Observable<any[]> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      onValue(this.messagesRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const messages = data ? Object.values(data) : [];
        observer.next(messages);
      });
    });
  }
}

so I'm trying to implement a real-time database of firebase to my service typescript file but this error appears : Property 'list' does not exist on type 'DatabaseReference'.
any solution ?
I tried to change the code but I got a similar error ( Property 'list' does not exist on type 'Database'

Screenshots of code/errors are not allowed, see [mre].

i saw someone posting a screenshot + i can post it , that's why i did't thought it's not allowed

It's not so much that screenshot are not allowed. It's that that they are difficult to work with on Stack Overflow.  Please copy the code into the question instead so it's easy for others to read, copy, and search.

done , but why my question is getting -1 ?

Someone must have downvoted it.  Always strive to write the best possible question to avoid that in the future.

You're configuring Firebase with its regular JavaScript SDK in your code, but then try to use the list() method which only exists in the AngularFire wrapper library.
If you want to use the AngularFire API, initialize and inject it as shown in the AngularFire developers guide for Realtime Database. From there:

As a prerequisite, ensure that AngularFire has been added to your project via
ng add @angular/fire

Provide a Database instance in the application's app.config.ts:
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideDatabase, getDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp({ ... })),
    provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})

Next inject Database into your component:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Database } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Component({...})
export class DepartmentComponent {
  private database = inject(Database);
  ...
}


You seem to have missed the first and the last part of that.

no the first and the second are already done

Your db variable is set to db = ref(this.database, "messages"), while in the docs they inject it. That's why db.list won't work for you.

now the error is gone and I changed the code here ( u can take a look at it ) , does it play the same role as the previous one ?

Sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. Your original code didn't work because of the reason I indicated. If you're getting another error after fixing the original problem, that's a new question. --- Also see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]

I'm not getting any error rn

Good to hear. Still leaves What should I do when someone answers my question?

The above answer (from @puf-FrankvanPuffelen) does resolve your error but doesn't resolve your problem completely though.
As mentioned in the answer earlier, you missed providing the Database instance in the application and injecting the database into your component/service.
Only thing left is to get the DataSnapshot changes as an observable and subscribe to it
Your Message Service
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Database, ref, listVal} from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {

    db = inject(Database);
    messagesRef = ref(this.database, "messages");
    
    getMessages(): Observable<any[]> {
       return listValue(messagesRef)
    }
}

And subscribe to the observable in the component
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../../services/message.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
...

export class MessageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  messageService = inject(MessageService)
  sub!: Subscription

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.messageService.getMessages().subscribe(messages=> {
    console.log(messages)
  })

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
  }
}
...

